# Why does dojo issue this error? Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'query'

Tags: javascript, dojo

This error appears to be happening in AutoCompleterMixin.js. I can't pinpoint the reason for this problem. I am running the web application in google chrome and I have checked that the AutoCompleterMixin.js file is present in the scripts. Why is this happening and how can I resolve it?
This is the code snipped which seems to be causing the problem.

```
dijit.byId("home").store=new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({data:information.list})
```

Comment: Are you suggesting it is broken for everyone?  If not, you have to show some code if you want meaningful answers.

Comment: http://poop.me.uk/~phenny/logs/dojo/2011/03/11.html#ln15 - suggests that it may occur if you're passing a dojo.data store to a component expecting a dojo.store - and -1 for not running your own google search on the problem initially (or, if you did, for not telling us the results of same)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the apparent lack of information. I did do a google search and found the same info i.e the component might be looking for a dojo.store where a dojo.data was being passed. The answer is that in 1.7.2 you need to set a FilteringSelect.

So, dijit.byId("home").set("x",dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({data:information.list})

would do the trick.